# Keycloak: Liquibase is trying to execute the changeset multiple times even though it's not change

Tags: keycloak, liquibase, changeset, changelog

I am running keycloak in a docker container. I have implemented custom JPA provider, added new changelog file under the `resources` directory of my extension and referred it in `getChangelogLocation` method of my provider.

It worked fine till now. Now, I wanted to rename one of the columns in the DB table I added in above changelog file. So I added new changeset entry with `renameColumn` change type. But when I am restarting my container, liquibase is trying to run the same changeset again even though the changeset entry is present in DATABASECHANGELOG history table. And it's failing obviously as the column is already renamed. I have not changed any info in the changeset configuration so not sure why liquibase is running it again.

Anyone has any idea or faced similar kind of issue?

Thanks,
Sagun

Comment: Liquibase runs whenever there is a change found in one of the following: changeset ID, the author or the chnagelog file, even if the path of the changelog file is changed. Have you made any change in these areas?

Have you made any changes to your setup? Eg. upgrade liquibase?

Comment: I added param `runOnChange="true"` for the changeset and forgot to take it out. It turned out because of this param, the liquibase was trying to execute the changeset everytime.